# I cannot call a php-script from bash

Tags: php, bash

As a newbie to the exciting world of raspberry pi i have to following situation.

On the one hand i have an raspi with an button connected to the gpio and a bash script that registers button presses. This works wonderful.

Also i have a php-script which reads the actual ip- and mac-adress of the raspi - this script works also wonderful when called on the build-in-browser on the raspi.

On the other hand i have an windows 2012r2 based iis with an asp.net webpage which awaits the call of this page by the raspi-php-script with the params ip and mac.

When i call the php-script on the raspi-browser everything works perfect. But the call by the bash-script is not even going out? What do i have to change?

Here is the bash-script:

```
#!/bin/sh

gpio mode 2 in
while true
do
result="$( gpio read 2 )"
if [ "$result" = "0" ]; then
php /var/www/html/buttom.php
echo "go"
fi

sleep 0.5
done
```

Here is the php-script "buttom.php"

```
#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php

$ip = trim(shell_exec("/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'"));
$mac = trim(shell_exec("/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:digit:]]{1,2}'"));

$search = array (0 => ':',);
$replace = array (0 => '',);
$subject = $mac;
$mac = (str_replace( $search, $replace, $subject) );

$vars = array('ip' => $ip, 'mac' => $mac);
$querystring = http_build_query($vars);

$url = "http://www.mydomain.de/inbound/buttom.aspx?".$querystring;

header("Location: $url");

?>
```

I would be so grateful for any advice :D

Comment: can you add "set -x" on your script. This will give you shell script debug logs. Also add that to the  question. type which php and get the result something like "/usr/bin/php". Try changing the shell script line "php /var/www/html/buttom.php" to <path to php(/usr/bin/php) /var/www/html/buttom.php>. Don't forget to update the question.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - where do i add set -x?

i also changed the path to php as you recommended but nothing happened...

Comment: i found out where to put it - the result is something like this:


+ /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/buttom.php

+ echo go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Provide full path to both PHP file and PHP binary, eg. `/usr/bin/php /var/www/myscript.php`. You might need root privileges as well.
2. Safer option might be calling your local server via curl, like this: `curl -s http://localhost/buttom.php`

EDIT. Ah, I see your problem. So your script launches. You run bash script, that executes PHP. And you are returning what? A header. I don't think bash console understands that ;)

Try calling your site from inside PHP.

Instead of

```
header("Location: $url");
```

Go for

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Try this and let us know did it work :)

More info on PHP curl function is available on manual page http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: `+ // /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/buttom.php
/var/www/buttom.sh: Zeile 10: //: Ist ein Verzeichnis
+ curl -s http://localhost/buttom.php
#!/usr/bin/php
+ echo go
go
`

This is the result of changing to curl - but still no call of aspx-page noticed on iis...

Comment: @Mark since he has "/usr/bin/php " inside his actual php script I don't think there is a need to give full path while invoking the script. Now that your script is getting invoked can you add some debug point inside your php script ("print statement ") and provide the output. I think we need to debug where exactly if comes out.

Comment: sorry again - i am really completely new to the linux bash/shell/php-world. Where do i insert the "print statement"?

Comment: Put some `echo "name of your point so you know we went this far";` inside your php script. You can also do some http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php and check what is inside your php variables

Comment: ok i added `echo ($url)` to the php-script, then ran the buttom.sh, pressed the button and then it showed the url including ip and mac-adress in the shell... so the script seems to be working - to me the fault seems to be that the php-script is called but does not call the aspx-page... as i said before: when i run the php within a browser everything is perfect... i am running to buttom.sh as standard "pi-user" - is this a problem?

Comment: I've edited my answer, maybe that would do the trick :)

Comment: @Mark: I edited the script as you suggested: now i receive the following: `PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()` but i feel this could be the right direction ;)

Comment: @MichaelHanning install the dependencies for curl - sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl

Comment: i just did that - now after pressing the button the shell shows the script of the aspx-page - but still the aspx-page is not called...

Comment: What do you mean - shows the script? The source code of your aspx page?

Comment: yup - the source code of aspx page... and in addition to that: the `echo ($url)` within the php-script does not show the ip-address

Comment: If it returns the source code, that means IIS returned it (so it was called). If IP address isn't showed, that means there is something in your php script that failed to get the address. Debug it using `var_dump` to see what do you have on each step.

Comment: nevermind the ip-address... this is something i can work out myself... but i don't have the slightest clue why the source code is shown instead of being processed. Someone an idea? As far as i already found out if i have `curl http://www.mydomain.de/inpund/button.aspx`in the shell it shows also the source code - is `curl`the right thing to call a page - instead of downloading it? Sorry for my lack of knowledge...

Comment: Do you know how IIS works? In simple words - it waits for requests, executes the .NET code inside ASPX page and then returns HTML string to you. Now what you are doing here is asking CURL to call that website, and echo the response. Read the response to find out if IIS returned HTML only (which means that the .NET code was executed) or contains some server side markup as well (incorrectly setup IIS). You can basicaly call the `$url` manually and the result should be the same.

Comment: ok - this was my fault: i have an jquery-script with `$(document).ready` which fires a function that calls an asmx-webservice to document the visit - now i have this function in the protected sub page-init: et voila everything is perfect. @mark @ varad A G Thank you so much for your patience and your thoughts

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution :)